# Retrieve value by key from dict in Python

Tags: python

Guys is there any way so that I can retrieve status value with `mylist['status']`

```
mylist = {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Winnetka",
               "short_name" : "Winnetka",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
         ],

   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please correct your code. You have not provided valid python, so we cannot see how your data is structured. Also, please read: **[mcve]**

Comment: you are missing `}` after "address_components" list

Comment: You gave the name `mylist` to something that isn't a list. Prepare to get hurt in code review.

Comment: Im pretty sure of  my_list and its type 
    print (type(my_list))
    #<class 'list'>
    print(my_list['status'])            
    #TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @VonClauseWitz Then the content of `myList` is __not__ what you paste here. What we’re seeing here is `myList` being a dictionary. We can't help further if what you’re asking is not the problem you’re having.

Answer (score 3):

Correct your code as follow (missing close parenthesis `}`)

```
mylist = {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Winnetka",
               "short_name" : "Winnetka",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
         ],
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

and afterwords you can call `mylist['status']`

```
> mylist['status'] 
OK
```

Comment: I did that but I got this error 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I think you forgot to fix the error in the answer…? ^_^" The closing brace should go between the two closing square brackets.

Comment: @poke right, i've copy-paste wrong, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I've reformatted your code below so it may make more sense to you:

```
mylist = {"results" : [{"address_components" : [{"long_name" : "Winnetka",
                                                 "short_name" : "Winnetka",
                                                 "types" : ["locality", "political"]}]}],
          "status" : "OK"}

mylist['status']  # 'OK'
```

Comment: I did that but I got this error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: are you copying my exact code?

Comment: Im not copying past into the console ,cause that works
I have the list coming from gmap python library and its type(mylist) == <class 'list'> 
but mylist['status'] produces that error !!!!!!!

Comment: sorry, can't help further without a [mcve].